# Is this algorithm for the function correct?

Tags: algorithm, function

The question I'm trying to solve is...

What is the value returned by the following function? Express your answer as a function of n.

[image]

```
int v = 0;
int n = 100;

for (int i = 1; i <= n ; i++)           
{
    for( int j = n + 1; j < 2 * n; j++)
    {
        v = v + 1;
    }
}

System.out.println(v);
```

Seems like I'm missing something but I don't know what. =/ Thank you.

Comment: What do you get for n=1? n=2? n=3? etc. Notice a pattern?

Comment: Why for the inner loop, it is `j < 2 * n` instead of `j <= 2* n`?

Comment: Hint: It is supposed to be `j <= (n*2)` in the inner loop.

Comment: Oh ya, ops it should be j <= 2 * n, thank you.

The outer loop goes from 1 - n, the inside loop goes from n+1 to 2n, which is n times, so it would just be n * n, n^2

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's a simple arithmetic puzzle.

Comment: We're actually learning about algorithms and Big O notation in school and this was one of the practice questions. I know java a bit so I'm trying to practice by programming the algorithms. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to give the whole answer away.

First of, our function looks like this.

```
int v = 0;            
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = (n + 1); j <= (n*2); j++) {
        v++;
    }
}
System.out.println(v);
```

So, depending on `n` what will `v` give us?

Let's try it, let's try for `n = 1` to 20

```
for (int n = 1; n < 20; n++) {

    int v = 0;            
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = (n + 1); j <= (n*2); j++) {
            v++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

Try that! If you still are curious give a poke here.

Hint #2. It is a very specific function, a very common.

Comment: What function was it? :)

Comment: Quadratic function xD

Comment: @nesan101 mark it as answer if you find it as your answer